# sorting the variable data in specific order in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a list of elements in a varibale x as below,

```
set x {NAB BRX_v NABLE_e M0_I2C GPIO INTERRUT STRAP0}
```

I want to arrange them in specific order and assign to other variable and use this list for further processing.

```
set y {STRAP0 M0_I2C BRX_v NAB GPIO NABLE_e INTERRUT}
```

I want it to do in TCL, but I am not getting any idea how can I do.
I can have a file which has the data in order. then I can compare the file data one by one with the variable `x`, if it is present will assign it to `y array[0]`. But how to do that.

Comment: If you know the desired order, why not write out the list in that order to start with?

Comment: How do we determine the order of the items? It's obviously not alphabetic or numeric.

Comment: Order matters. And searching and writing to variable should be in order only

Comment: When sorting the `$y` list, where do you want to put the extra items of `$y` which aren't in `$x`?    Or have you neglected to tell us that `$y` will only be composed of items which are already in `$x`?

Comment: $y will only have items of $X.

Answer (score 0):

Does order really matter for what you want to do?   It sounds like you are looking for items in list `y` that are present in list `x`.

This would be a simple way to do that in the `in` operator:

```
foreach item $y {
    if {$item in $x} {
        puts "$item is in list x"
    }
}
```

For bigger and bigger list lengths, the `in` operator will not be as fast as dictionary key lookup.

```
# Create a dictionary from list x, with a dummy value of '1' for each key.
set dict_x [dict create]
foreach item $x {
    dict set dict_x $item 1
}

foreach item $y {
    if {[dict exists $dict_x $item]} {
        puts "$item is in list x"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some sort of mapping from those names to an ordering. The ordering definition doesn't say what names are present, but if they are then it says what order they should be in.

There are two ways to express that order in Tcl:

1. Via a mapping (array or dictionary) from names to explicit ordering values
2. Via a list (where the position in the list is the implicit ordering term)

You can use that ordering term to order an actual list of values, but you need to compute a list of order values ("collation keys") *or* (less efficiently) to create a list of composite values where you have the collation keys in there with the values which they describe. I currently prefer to use the first approach, which is based on the `-indices` option to `lsort`; the other approach instead uses `-index` to pick out a part of each element to use as the collation key, and requires stripping at the end. Or you could use `-command`, but that has quite a bit of execution overhead (especially if you need `lsearch` to find the key).

## Using a mapping in an array

```
# Note that I don't know what the values should be, but they should be distinct integers
array set ORDERING {
    NAB      1
    BRX_v    2
    NABLE_e  4
    M0_I2C   8
    GPIO     16
    INTERRUT 32
    STRAP0   64
}
set aux [lsort -integer -indices [lmap val $x {set ORDERING($val)}]]
set y [lmap idx $aux {lindex $x $idx}]
```

## Using a mapping in a dict

This might look a bit similar to code above!

```
# Note that I don't know what the values should be, but they should be distinct integers
set ORDERING {
    NAB      1
    BRX_v    2
    NABLE_e  4
    M0_I2C   8
    GPIO     16
    INTERRUT 32
    STRAP0   64
}
set aux [lsort -integer -indices [lmap val $x {dict get $ORDERING $val}]]
set y [lmap idx $aux {lindex $x $idx}]
```

## Using a mapping in a list

```
# In this case, the ordering is implicit
set ORDERING {
    NAB
    BRX_v
    NABLE_e
    M0_I2C
    GPIO
    INTERRUT
    STRAP0
}
set aux [lsort -integer -indices [lmap val $x {lsearch -exact $ORDERING $val}]]
set y [lmap idx $aux {lindex $x $idx}]
```

Comment: I want to emphasise again that I don't know what order the values should actually be. It's obviously not alphabetic. But the approach I describe will handle sorting these things with whatever ordering you want to use.

Comment: Also, `aux` is only used because I think the line gets too long otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still feeling like you really don't need to re-order `$y`.   Your actual goal is to figure out what elements of `$x` are not present in `$y`, right?

You could iterate anyway over `$x` and construct a new list composed of elements of `$x` which are also in `$y`.

```
set x {NAB BRX_v NABLE_e M0_I2C GPIO INTERRUT STRAP0}
set y {STRAP0 M0_I2C BRX_v NAB GPIO NABLE_e INTERRUT}

set y_sorted [list]
foreach item $x {
    if {$item in $y} {
        lappend y_sorted $item
    } else {
        puts "$item not in y"
    }
}
```

Once you have `$y_sorted`, then I think you're interested to use the list to report which items in `$y_sorted` are not in `$x`.  However, you wouldn't need any extra step to get that information because it was already printed with the `puts` statements.